# Determining the element that occurred the most in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: java, c, algorithm

Let me start off by saying that this is not a homework question. I am trying to design a cache whose eviction policy depends on entries that occurred the most in the cache. In software terms, assume we have an array with different elements and we just want to find the element that occurred the most. For example: {1,2,2,5,7,3,2,3} should return 2. Since I am working with hardware, the naive O(n^2) solution would require a tremendous hardware overhead. The smarter solution of using a hash table works well for software because the hash table size can change but in hardware, I will have a fixed size hash table, probably not that big, so collisions will lead to wrong decisions. My question is, in software, can we solve the above problem in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space?

Comment: Do you have max limit to which elements can occur?

Comment: @Aniket it is pretty big because it is part of the physical address, around 20 bits

Comment: Is there some limit on the maximum number of elements that can be in the array?

Comment: @NikunjBanka Yes, the limit is the cache size. It is big but finite

Comment: Are you allowed to mutate the array - sorting it, for example? Also, since it's a cache, would an inexact heuristic be a viable option?

Comment: Which entries do you evict, those with the most occurences, or those with least? I.e. what happens when you fill the entire cache? Do you discard elements which occurs least times, and then insert the new item?

Comment: What is going into the cache? What performance requirements do you have for adding things to the cache? It would be possible to have rapid removal if you were willing to add extra work at insertion or load the objects cached with extra tracking data.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would have duplicate items in the cache at all. I'd approach the problem by maintaining a counter for each item, which indicates how many times it's been accessed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the input array denotes (read) access operations to the cache. But is the array known all at once or do you need an online algorithm? The latter is usual case for caches. For online algorithms there is another feature to be taken into account beside space and runtime: The quality of the solution. Do you need "guaranteed optimal solution"? This is usually impossible for online algorithms. Is a bound on divergence from optimal solution required/sufficient? Which bound? Are you aware that O(1) can be quite big, if you specify the cache size to be **constant**?

Comment: How big are the items?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There can't be an `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space solution, at least not for the generic case.

As [amit points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261128/determining-the-element-that-occured-the-most-in-on-time-and-o1-space/23261412?noredirect=1#comment35604702_23261412), by solving this, we find the solution to the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) (determining whether all the elements of a list are distinct), which has been proven to take `Θ(n log n)` time when not using elements to index the computer's memory. If we were to use elements to index the computer's memory, given an unbounded range of values, this requires at least `Θ(n)` space. Given the reduction of this problem to that one, the bounds for that problem enforces identical bounds on this problem.

However, practically speaking, the range would mostly be bounded, if for no other reason than the type one typically uses to store each element in has a fixed size (e.g. a 32-bit integer). If this is the case, this would allow for an `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space solution, albeit possibly too slow and using too much space due to the large constant factors involved (as the time and space complexity would depend on the range of values).

2 options:

- [**Counting sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

  > Keeping an array of the number of occurrences of each element (the array index being the element), outputting the most frequent.

  If you have a bounded range of values, this approach would be `O(1)` space (and `O(n)` time). But technically so would the hash table approach, so the constant factors here is presumably too large for this to be acceptable.

  Related options are [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (has an in-place variant, similar to quicksort) and [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).
- [**Quicksort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

  > Repeatedly partitioning the data based on a selected pivot (through swapping) and recursing on the partitions.

  After sorting we can just iterate through the array, keeping track of the maximum number of consecutive elements.

  This would take `O(n log n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Comment: `I don't believe an O(n) time, O(1) space` you can drop the "I don't believe", there isn't. if there was solving distinctness problem could be done in O(n) time and O(1) space, by running the algorithm to get a candidate and then check its number of occurances. Your answer pretty much summarizes the possibilities, so +1.

Comment: @amit Thanks. I (hopefully accurately) incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: I don't know a lower bound that says ED cannot be solved in that expected time and space using a randomized algorithm like a hash table. Reference?

Comment: @NiklasB. According to Wikipedia, the hash table solution falls under using elements to index the computer's memory, and thus aren't subject to these time and space bounds. But Wikipedia also mentions that the same lower bound was proven for randomized algorithms that don't fall under this, i.e. randomized algebraic decision tree model algorithms.

Comment: I can't extract that at all from the Wikipedia article, but if you say so

Comment: The algorithm discussed in the Wikipedia algorithm is solving the problem for a set of numbers drawn from the reals. It does not follow that it generalises to all classes of numbers. For example, it is trivially simply to do it in O(n) time and O(1) space for integers drawn from the interval [0,32). I believe that the set of numbers the asker is dealing with mean it is also possible for their collection (see my answer below).

Comment: @JackAidley I did make the distinction between bounded and unbounded integer ranges in my answer (claiming that running time is reachable for bounded integer ranges). Wikipedia doesn't seem to explicitly mention real values, but it's certainly possible that the referenced article does, although I doubt that distinction would be sufficient to invalidate the running time.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes, the bit about reals is in the referenced article not in the Wikipedia article. I think it's a key requirement, if you have an enumerable set and sufficient space to count in you can always solve it in O(n) time.

Answer (score 3):

As you say maximum element in your cache may e a very big number but following is one of the solution.

1. Iterate over the array.
2. Lets say maximum element that the array holds is m.
3. For each index i get the element it holds let it be array[i]
4. Now go to the index array[i] and add m to it.
5. Do above for all the indexes in array.
6. Finally iterate over the array and return index with maximum element.

TC -> O(N)
SC -> O(1)

It may not be feasible for large m as in your case. But see if you can optimize or alter this algo.

Answer (score 3):

A solution on top off my head :
As the numbers can be large , so i consider hashing , instead of storing them directly in array .

Let there are n numbers `0` to `n-1` .
Suppose the number occcouring maximum times , occour `K` times .
Let us create `n/k` buckets , initially all empty.

`hash(num)` tells whether `num` is present in any of the bucket .
`hash_2(num)` stores number of times `num` is present in any of the bucket .

for(i = 0 to n-1)

- if the number is already present in one of the buckets ,   increase the count of `input[i]` , something like   `Hash_2(input[i]) ++`
- else find an empty bucket , insert `input[i]` in 1st empty   bucket . `Hash(input[i])` `=` `true`
- else , if all buckets full , decrease count of **all** numbers   in buckets by 1 , don't add `input[i]` in any of buckets .
  If count of any number becomes zero [see hash_2(number)],  `Hash(number)` `=` `false` .

This way , finally you will get **atmost** k elements , and the required number is one of them , so you need to traverse the input again `O(N)` to finally find the  actual number .

The space used is `O(K)` and time complexity is `O(N)` , considering implementaion of hash `O(1)`.
So , the performance really depends on `K` . If `k << n` , this method perform poorly .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this answers the question as stated in the title, but actually you can implement a cache with the Least-Frequently-Used eviction policy having constant average time for put, get and remove operations. If you maintain your data structure properly, there's no need to scan all items in order to find the item to evict.

The idea is having a hash table which maps keys to value records. A value record contains the value itself plus a reference to a "counter node". A counter node is a part of a doubly linked list, and consists of:

- An access counter
- The set of keys having this access count (as a hash set)
- next pointer
- prev pointer

The list is maintained such that it's always sorted by the access counter (where the head is min), and the counter values are unique. A node with access counter C contains all keys having this access count. Note that this doesn't increment the overall space complexity of the data structure.

A get(K) operation involves promoting K by migrating it to another counter record (either a new one or the next one in the list).

An eviction operation triggered by a put operation roughly consists of checking the head of the list, removing an arbitrary key from its key set, and then removing it from the hash table.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if we make reasonable (to me, anyway) assumptions about your data set.

As you say you could do it if you could hash, because you can simply count-by-hash. The problem is that you may get non-unique hashes. You mention 20bit numbers, so presumably 2^20 possible values and a desire for a small and fixed amount of working memory for the actual hash counts. This, one presumes, will therefore lead to hash collisions and thus a breakdown of the hashing algorithm. But you can fix this by doing more than one pass with complementary hashing algorithms.

Because these are memory addresses, it's likely not all of the bits are actually going to be capable of being set. For example if you only ever allocate word (4 byte) chunks you can ignore the two least significant bits. I suspect, but don't know, that you're actually only dealing with larger allocation boundaries so it may be even better than this.

Assuming word aligned; that means we have 18 bits to hash.

Next, you presumably have a maximum cache size which is presumably pretty small. I'm going to assume that you're allocating a maximum of <=256 items because then we can use a single byte for the count.

Okay, so to make our hashes we break up the number in the cache into two nine bit numbers, in order of significance highest to lowest and discard the last two bits as discussed above. Take the first of these chunks and use it as a hash to give a first part count. Then we take the second of these chunks and use it as a hash but this time we only count if the first part hash matches the one we identified as having the highest hash. The one left with the highest hash is now uniquely identified as having the highest count.

This runs in O(n) time and requires a 512 byte hash table for counting. If that's too large a table you could divide into three chunks and use a 64 byte table.

**Added later**

I've been thinking about this and I've realised it has a failure condition: if the first pass counts two groups as having the same number of elements, it cannot effectively distinguish between them. Oh well

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: all the element is integer,for other data type we can also achieve this if we using hashCode()

We can achieve a time complexity **O(nlogn)** and space is **O(1)**.

First, sort the array , time complexity is O(nlog n) (we should use in - place sorting algorithm like **quick sort** in order to maintain the space complexity)

Using four integer variable, `current` which indicates the value we are referring to,`count` , which indicate the number of occurrences of `current`, `result` which indicates the finale result and `resultCount`, which indicate the number of occurrences of `result`

Iterating from start to end of the array `data`

```
  int result = 0;
  int resultCount = -1;
  int current = data[0];
  int count = 1;

  for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
       if(data[i] == current){
            count++;
      }else{
           if(count > resultCount){
               result = current;
               resultCount = count;
           }
           current = data[i];
           count = 1;
       }
  }
  if(count > resultCount){
      result = current;
      resultCount = count;
  }
  return result;
```

So, in the end, there is only 4 variables is used.

Comment: log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n) = log(1*2*....*n) = log(n!) which is in Theta(nlogn). I don't understand where your claim for almost O(n) comes from.

Comment: In addition, inserting an element to an arbitrary location in an array is O(n), because you need to "push" all elements to its right one step further. If you want to use a tree/skip list to obtain O(logn), you are going to suffer from much higher constants.

Comment: (I downvoted before the answer was fixed, and revoked my downvote when it was)

Comment: @PhamTrung: sorry, I did this by mistake. I didn't see the fix. Please do a dummy edit in your answer so I can cancel my downvote.

Comment: @EyalSchneider It's ok :)

Comment: @EyalSchneider You can also do the dummy edit yourself in these cases ;)